# Can't get data from table if table's name have number character

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a problem with my SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

I creat a database then creat a table in it. I write a small demo to get data from table. but if my table's name without number (tablenamea, tablenameb,...), I can't get data, if I insert 1 or more number into table 's name (tablenamea1, tablenameb12,..), I can get data. (Attach 2 picture)

table name with number
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/619694
The name without number
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/619695
whitout number

Why? and how to fix it?

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User` is a [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx), use instead:

```
select * from [User]
```

Or maybe consider using another name for your table.

> Although it is syntactically possible to use SQL Server reserved keywords as identifiers and object names in Transact-SQL scripts, you can do this only by using delimited identifiers.

Comment: Thank you, I thing I have a other table same as name.